# I get error whenever I run this program C++. What I am doing wrong

Tags: c++

```
#include   <iostream>
#include   <string>

using namespace std;

class Port{    

public:

    string Name( string x);


};

int main(){    

    Port Object;    

    Object.Name( "sword of ceaser");    


    cout << Object.Name();

}
```

Comment: Where is the implementation of the member function Name()?

Comment: How do you run this program? It can't be compiled.

Comment: `I get error whenever I run this program C++` You forgot to say what error that was. We can't just guess...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? Do you really want a method `Name` or do you want a member `Name`?

Comment: @Borgleader “Candidates expects 1 arguments , 0 provided “

Comment: You can't call `Object.Name()` without argument. You can overload the method `Name` with `void Name( string x);` and `string Name( );`

Comment: @ThomasSablik I tried to create a function and pass some string parameters, then call it in main with a string argument and have the output of whatever string argument I had given it. I might be wrong but I just started c++, so forgive my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need an implementation of the method (function) `Name`. How can the compiler know what to do if you don't tell. You can overload the method `Name` with `void Name( string x)` and `string Name( )`.

Next you need a member to store this value.

```
#include   <iostream>
#include   <string>

class Port{    
public:
    void Name(std::string x) {
        name = x;
    }
    std::string Name() {
        return name;
    }

private:
    std::string name;
};

int main(){    
    Port Object;    
    Object.Name( "sword of ceaser");    

    std::cout << Object.Name();
}
```

You should avoid `using namespace std;`. It's a bad habit.

Comment: Could you explain more to me about using namespace std; About it being a bad habit, I’m new to it. And it looks easier to me

Comment: @user11688094 See this question: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)